# Visual Studio Online: How to remove the New/Approved/Committed column on the sprint board

Tags: azure-devops

How can I remove these columns on a sprint board with tasks in Visual Studio Online:

[image]

There seem to be no reason for them there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're there because you have bugs configured to be treated as tasks. [You can adjust that at the team level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Work/customize/show-bugs-on-backlog).

[image]